# Xcode Cocoa default picker animation not animating for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

So I've followed everything this post [Default Picker Value iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625880/default-picker-value-iphone) says, but I can't seem to get my picker to work.

Here's my .m snippet:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.arrPercent = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20",@"21",@"22",@"23",@"24",@"25",@"26",@"27",@"28",@"29",@"30",@"31",@"32",@"33",@"34",@"35",@"36",@"37",@"38",@"39",@"40",@"41",@"42",@"43",@"44",@"45",@"46",@"47",@"48",@"49",@"50"];
    self.arrPeople = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20"];

    self.percent = [NSNumber numberWithInt:15];
    self.people = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
    self.strSubTotal = @"";

    self.myPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.myPicker.delegate = self;
}    
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //[self.myPicker selectRow:self.percent.integerValue inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    [self.myPicker selectRow:5 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    [self.myPicker selectRow:5 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
    [self.myPicker reloadAllComponents]; // tried commenting out this line with no luck
}
```

Here's my .h snippet:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *arrPercent;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *arrPeople;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *myPicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *strSubTotal;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *percent;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *people;

@end
```

Here's the delegate stuff, I think...

```
// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
    if(component== 0)
    {
        return [self.arrPercent count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self.arrPeople count];
    }
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self.arrPercent objectAtIndex:row], @"%"];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self.arrPeople objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0)
    {
        self.percent = [self.arrPercent objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
    {
        self.people = [self.arrPeople objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    [self updateSubTotal:-3];
}
```

When I start the emulator, the picker doesn't animate to the position I tell it to. Am I doing anything wrong? Please help!

Comment: What do you see? Is the picker populated?

Comment: Where are the picker's delegate methods? can u post it.

Comment: I've updated the question with more of my code. Thanks!

Comment: You still haven't said what it *does* do. Is it showing the values for the first row? Is it showing the data for the 5th row, but not animating to it?

Comment: @rdelmar I figured it out. Will post the answer in a bit!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the error was that for some reason, the connection between the picker in the UI was disconnected with the code. I had to hold the Control key while dragging the picker from the UI to the .h file.

I saw this because I noticed a little "empty button icon" next to the method declaration in the .h file. Once Xcode understood that the picker is controlled by the piece of code, everything works as expected.

Thank you so much!